# What is the difference between outerHTML and XMLSerializer().serializeToString(SvgNode)?

Tags: javascript, node.js, web, svg

What is the difference between `SVGNode.outerHTML` and `XMLSerializer().serializeToString(SVGNode)`?

The result seems to be the same.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 7):

XMLSerializer will produce a valid XML markup, while `outerHTML` will only output HTML.

SVG in HTML is way more lax than when it's parsed as a standalone XML document. For instance, in HTML you can omit the `xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"` on the root `<svg>`, as a standalone doc you can't. This is also true for any *namespaced* attributes, HTML doesn't have a concept of namespace. XMLSerializer will add it back to you, while `outerHTML` won't.  Another minor difference is that in HTML, only void elements can omit their end tags. At parsing the HTML parser will also allow elements inside and `<svg>` node, but when you'll get the `outerHTML`, the serializer will add it back. The XMLSerializer won't.

```js
const svgNode = document.querySelector("svg");
console.log("outerHTML", svgNode.outerHTML)
console.log("XMLSerializer", new XMLSerializer().serializeToString(svgNode))
```

```html
<svg><rect width=30 height=30 /></svg>
```

Note that these points are important because if you want to load the generated string as an SVG image, only the one produced by the XMLSerializer will work:

```js
const svgNode = document.querySelector("svg");
const outerImg = new Image();
outerImg.src = "data:image/svg+xml," + encodeURIComponent(svgNode.outerHTML);
document.body.append("outerHTML:", outerImg, document.createElement("br"));

const serializerImg = new Image();
serializerImg.src = "data:image/svg+xml," + encodeURIComponent( new XMLSerializer().serializeToString(svgNode));
document.body.append("XMLSerializer:", serializerImg, document.createElement("br"));
```

```css
img, svg { vertical-align: top }
```

```html
svg:<svg><rect width=30 height=30 /></svg><br>
```